# How do you get Algolia Autocomplete to work with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, autocomplete, algolia

On the [Algolia Autocomplete Github](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete), the readme says, "The data that populates the autocomplete results are called sources. **You can use whatever you want** in your sources...". However, what I've found is there is barely any documentation on using data sources other than Algolia, and whatever documentation there is, is vague. Once you're a few hours into it, you realize it's practically a bait-and-switch. You were promised an autocomplete component that you could use with any data source, but what you find out is the whole thing is designed to lock you into using Algolia.

Look, all I want to do is create a REST endpoint in Laravel 10 and return some dummy data. For example:

`routes/api.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'index']);
```

`app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $results = [
            'results' => [
                ['apple'],
                ['banana'],
                ['strawberry']
            ]
        ];

        return response()->json($results);
    }
}
```

GET request via JS Fetch to API endpoint: `http://localhost/api/test`

Response:

*Note: I don't know if this is even in the correct format. I can't find any documentation on this!*

```json
{
   "results":[
      [
         "apple"
      ],
      [
         "banana"
      ],
      [
         "strawberry"
      ]
   ]
}
```

Here is the Algolia boilerplate:

```html
<div id="autocomplete"></div>
```

```js
import { autocomplete } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';

import '@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic';

autocomplete({
  container: '#autocomplete',
  placeholder: 'Search for products',
  getSources() {
    // What goes here instead of returning an empty array?
    return [];
  },
});
```

Comment: I've not used `algolia` myself, but have you seen [their getting started example](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/introduction/getting-started/#defining-where-to-put-your-autocomplete)? Seems like far more information there that could be helpful.

Comment: @PaulT. Yea, that's actually where I copied the boilerplate from. There are numerous examples of using Algolia as a data source, and a few others that use [Google Maps and static sources](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/core-concepts/sources/), but I can't find any examples of using a custom REST endpoint, even though the promise of this library is "you can use whatever you want" and I'd imagine most developers looking for an autocomplete library want to use their own REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I've figured it out.

Here's a static example:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ust0chb8/)

```js
autocomplete({
  container: '#autocomplete',
  placeholder: 'Search for fruit',
  getSources({ query }) {
    return [
      {
      sourceId: 'suggestions',
      getItems() {
        return [
          {
            name: 'apple'
          },
          {
            name: 'banana'
          },
          {
            name: 'strawberry'
          }
        ].filter(({ name }) =>
          name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        );
      },
      templates: {
        item({ item }) {
          return `${item.name}`;
        },
        noResults() {
          return 'No fruit matching.';
        },
      },
      },
    ];
  },
});
```

The REST endpoint autocomplete would look something like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'query'  => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status'  => 'error',
                'message' => 'Invalid request.'
            ], 400);
        }

        $query = $request->input('query');

        $fruits = collect([
            ['name' => 'apple'],
            ['name' => 'banana'],
            ['name' => 'strawberry']
        ])->filter(function ($item) use ($query) {
            // Similar to "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'foo%';".
            return str_starts_with($item['name'], $query);
        });

        $results = [];

        foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
            $results[] = $fruit;
        }

        return response()->json([
            'results' => $results
        ]);
    }
}
```

```js
autocomplete({
  container: '#autocomplete',
  placeholder: 'Search for fruit',
  getSources({ query }) {
    return [
      {
        sourceId: 'suggestions',
        getItems() {
          return fetch('/api/test?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query))
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              return data.results;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              return [];
            });
        },
        templates: {
          item({ item }) {
            return `${item.name}`;
          },
          noResults() {
            return 'No results matching.';
          },
        },
      },
    ];
  },
});
```

To take some action (such as updating the text in the search box) when a result is selected:

```js
// After templates:
onSelect: function(event) {
  event.setQuery(event.item.name);
  console.log(event.item);
}
```

Handles a submission like the user pressing the enter key without a list item selected:

```js
// After getSources:
onSubmit({ state }) {
  console.log(state);
}
```